# How to stop all classes toggle when use toggleClass in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to stop all classes toggle when using toggleClass in jQuery.

I have implemented the jQuery function to toggle icon 180 degrees by using the following code.

HTML:

```
{{#each menu}}
 <ul id="myUL">
    <div class="menu-text">
      <li><span class="caret treeparent">&nbsp;{{@key}}<i class="fas fa-chevron-down arrow"></i></span>
        <ul class="tog">
        {{#each this}}
           <li class="nav-item">
              <a>{{{this.label}}}</a>
           </li>
        {{/each}}
        </ul>
      </li>
    </div>
 </ul>
 {{/each}}
```

jQuery:

```
$(".treeparent").click(function () {
    $(".arrow").toggleClass('flip');
});
```

CSS

```
.arrow {
    -moz-transition: transform 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.6s;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
  }

.flip {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

Then all icons are rotating 180 degrees. What I want to do is rotate only the clicked div icon. For fixing the problem I used the following code.

```
$(".treeparent").click(function () {
  $(this).next('.arrow').toggleClass('flip');
});
```

But then rotation also not working. How Can I fix this?

Comment: You'll need to include your HTML to see how the .treeparent and .arrow are related

Comment: @freedomn-m edited the question with adding HTML part

Comment: i think that the most simple solution will be to add an id for the tag that you wish to toggle, and just query by it's id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case as `.arrow` is contained by `.treeparent` you should be able to modify your click function for this one

```js
$(".treeparent").click(function () {
  $(".arrow", this).toggleClass('flip');
});
```

`$(selector, element)` will look for `selector` contained in the given `element`, in this case this which is the `.treeparent` clicked

PS. if you planning to have neested element I recommend to change the selector to `>.arrow` so only point to first child.

HTH

Thanks @Swati for provide the code snippet

```js
$(".treeparent").click(function () {
  $(".arrow", this).toggleClass('flip');
});
```

```css
.arrow {
    -moz-transition: transform 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.6s;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
  }

.flip {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul id="myUL">
  <div class="menu-text">
    <li><span class="caret treeparent">&nbsp;{{@key}}<i class="fa fa-chevron-down arrow"></i></span>
      <ul class="tog">
      
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a>{{{this.label}}}</a>
        </li>
       
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
<ul id="myUL">
  <div class="menu-text">
    <li><span class="caret treeparent">&nbsp;{{@key}}<i class="fa fa-chevron-down arrow"></i></span>
      <ul class="tog">
       
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a>{{{this.label}}}</a>
        </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
          <a>{{{this.label}}}</a>
        </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
          <a>{{{this.label}}}</a>
        </li>
       
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the closest div i.e : `menu-text` then use `.find()` to get the `<i>` where you need to toggle class.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".treeparent").click(function () {
//get this closest ->find arrow class toggle class or use .closest("li")
  $(this).closest(".menu-text").find(".arrow").toggleClass('flip');
});
```

```css
.arrow {
    -moz-transition: transform 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.6s;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
  }

.flip {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul id="myUL">
  <div class="menu-text">
    <li><span class="caret treeparent">&nbsp;{{@key}}<i class="fa fa-chevron-down arrow"></i></span>
      <ul class="tog">
      
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a>{{{this.label}}}</a>
        </li>
       
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
<ul id="myUL">
  <div class="menu-text">
    <li><span class="caret treeparent">&nbsp;{{@key}}<i class="fa fa-chevron-down arrow"></i></span>
      <ul class="tog">
       
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a>{{{this.label}}}</a>
        </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
          <a>{{{this.label}}}</a>
        </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
          <a>{{{this.label}}}</a>
        </li>
       
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```